# How do I maintain a persistent SQLite connection in a Safari Web Extension?

Tags: database, macos, sqlite, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that:

- pulls webpage content with *content.js*
- insert the content in a SQLite database that is persistently stored on the hard disk

I have realised that [SafariWebExtensionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionhandler) only lives in a tab. That means every time the extension wants to insert data to the database, it has to re-initiate a connection to the SQLite file.

I'm wondering if there's a way to improve this to the state where there is a background SQLite instance that I could connect to any time from the extension JavaScript context.

My thoughts:

- Run a background daemon on macOS that maintains the SQLite connection. The daemon serves as an WebSocket server. The extension JavaScript connects to it via WebSocket.

  - Cons: a background process is required. The Safari API `browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage` was not used.

I'm thinking there's definitely a API that I have missed that would be suitable for this scenario. I'm completely new to macOS development, so please eli5.